# How to add a new executable with cabal/stack?

Tags: haskell, build, cabal

I'd like to add a new executable to my project. But it is unable to parse the `MyProject.cabal` at `build-depends`. When I remove `MyProject` from the `build-depends` it says that it can't find the target `TestExample`

I tried to load the `TestExample` like this: `stack ghci TestExample`

```
name:                  MyProject
cabal-version:         >=1.10


library
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  exposed-modules:     MyProject
                     , MyProject.Other
  build-depends:       base
                     , text


executable TestExample
  hs-source-dirs:      examples
  main-is:             TestExample.hs
  build-depends:       base
                     , MyProject
                     , MyProject.Other
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cabal file `build-depends` is a list of packages, not modules.

```
  build-depends:       base
                     , MyProject
                     , MyProject.Other
```

Here `base` is a package, `MyProject` is a name of your library package (see `name` field in the cabal file), but `MyProject.Other` is not a package. Actually dot is [not allowed](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#package-names-and-versions) in package names:

> Cabal package names can use letters, numbers and hyphens, but not
>   spaces.

That is why cabal can't parse the file. Just remove `, MyProject.Other` line from `build-depends` and it should work.

And to load sources into interpreter, use `stack ghci`.

Comment: It doesn't, stack tells me `The following target packages were not found: TestExample`

Comment: @TomTom What `stack build` says? I think now you have an issue with `stack`, it is different from the initial one.

Comment: It can't load .so/.DLL and tells me there is an undefined symbol in `libHSMyProject .. lot symbols .. ghc7.10.3.so`. Called again with a lot of symbols and `info` at the end

Comment: @TomTom Looks like you didn't list all modules in library `exposed-modules` section. Could you share the complete example? E.g. create a repo on github.

Comment: I managed to compile it. You were right. I exposed all the modules in the project and renamed the module `TestExample` to `Main` inside the file. However it still isn't found when I run `stack ghci TestExample`

Comment: @TomTom I rarely use `stack`, but something like `stack ghci MyProject:TestExample` seems to work. Or you can just `stack ghci` and load what you need by hands.

Comment: I will figure that out somehow. But the module loads as well when I just use `stack ghci`. Could you extend your answer so I can accept it?